# Most efficient way to make an activity log

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a "recent activity" tab to profiles on my site and I also am going to have a log for moderators to see everything that happens on the site. This would require making an activity log of some sort.

I just don't know what would be better. I have 2 options:

1. Make a table called "activity" and then every time someone does something, add a record to it with the type of action, user id, timestamp, etc.

   - **Problem:** table could get very long.
2. Join all 3 tables (questions, answers, answer_comments) and then somehow show all these on the page in the order in which the action was taken.

   - **Problem:** this would be extremely hard because I have no clue how I could make it say *"John commented on an answer on Question Title Here"* by just joining 3 tables.

Does anyone know of a better way of making an activity log in this situation? I am using PHP and MySQL. If this is either too inefficient or hard I will probably just forget the Recent Activity tab on profiles but I still need an activity log for moderators.

Here's some SQL that I started making for option 2, but this would not work because there is no way of detecting whether the action is a comment, question, or answer when I echo the info in a `while` loop:

```
SELECT q.*, a.*, ac.* 
    FROM questions q JOIN answers a ON a.questionid = q.qid
        JOIN answer_comments ac ON c.answerid = a.ans_id
WHERE q.user = $userid 
AND a.userid = $userid 
AND ac.userid = $userid
    ORDER BY q.created DESC, a.created DESC, ac.created DESC
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have `q.user` and `q.userid`?

For option 2 (the better option IMO - as long as you've indexed properly), I think a `UNION` is more what you're looking for. Something like this:

```
SELECT 'question' AS action, id, created 
    FROM questions WHERE userid = {$userid}
    UNION
SELECT 'answer' AS action, id, created
    FROM answers WHERE userid = {$userid}
    UNION
SELECT 'comment' AS action, id, created
    FROM answer_comments WHERE userid = {$userid}
ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 20
```

The `'question' / 'answer' / 'comment'` tells you which action was taken. Possible issues you may run into: being a `UNION`, each `SELECT` statement must have the same number of columns, so if one is short, you can just add a `NULL` e.g.:

```
SELECT 'comment', id, created, NULL FROM ac
```

Also, if one of the `created` columns has a different name you can just alias

```
SELECT 'comment', id, comment_date AS created FROM ac
```

Comment: Sorry, the second one should actually be `a.userid` (that was a typo). Anyway thanks a lot! I'm going to try this and if it works I will be accepting your answer :D And thanks for that way of identifying if it's a comment, question, or answer because I never knew you could do that.

Comment: This pretty much works :) I'm just having a small problem with joining the question table to get the question info so it can be linked and stuff. Here is the SQL and PHP: http://screencast.com/t/EJgdGkMPBB For some reason on comments it seem so tbe showing the question id as the title and then for answers it isn't showing the title at all: http://screencast.com/t/qvDzliDs9U I am aware that some of the stuff isn't in yet like `$row['qSlug']` and stuff (which is the URL slug of the title) but that shouldn't affect the other stuff.

Comment: The name of the associative key comes from the **first** `SELECT`. You should select all of the common columns first (`id, created, q_id, q_title`), then select the distinct columns last (`a.ans_id` and `ac.id`). This is not a flaw - `UNION` is designed for selecting the same data. As for the blank title, you are using `qTitle` instead of `q_title`.

Comment: Did this help? I would appreciate an "accept" or if you're still having trouble I'm happy to help out

Comment: I accepted it. Thanks for the help, this is a good solution and a lot better than making a whole table for the activity log.

Answer (score 1):

I like "option 2", you would basically be duplicating your data and it would slow things down a bit with the extra reads/writes. Maybe instead of doing a

```
SELECT q.*, a.*, ac.*
```

You could either just get the data that you need from each table, or a slightly cleaner way may be to do a [Union](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx) of the three tables, after limiting your query to only those posts by selected user, and order by the date posted.

Comment: This looks like a good idea but in a while loop how could I detect if the action is an answer, question, or comment? If I can do that, then this will work and I could say: "{User} commented on an answer on Question Title" if it's a comment and then "{User} asked Question Title" if it's a question, etc.

Comment: you can add in a variable for type, for example in each of the select statements throw in a string for what it is: select 'question' as activity_type, q.field1, etc from ...